# Changing values of textboxes based on other textboxes;

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 text boxes and i have to handle the textchanged events of both.The user can enter either of those textboxes and based on where the user did the input,the other one needs to be changed.To prevent them going into an infinite loop,i get the sender in c# but i just can not do it in VB.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If (sender Is TextBox1) Then
        txtmt.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox1.Text) * 0.9144
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtmt_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtmt.TextChanged
    If (sender Is txtmt) Then
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox1.Text) / 0.9144
    End If
End Sub
```

How do we do that in VB ? And also avoid null vlaues?

Comment: What do you mean, you “get the sender in C#”? You can do the same in VB (indeed your code does that) but that doesn’t help you at all since it won’t prevent the recursion.

Comment: why need to change to decimal?

Comment: c# habit i guess..My first time in VB,have to get this over with,hated it already :)

Comment: Well how would you do it in C#? If you have a solution you can translate it literally 1:1 to VB.

Comment: I actually tried it,just could figure out which was :if (sender == spinEditYrd)
   {
    spinEditMt.EditValue = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(spinEditYrd.EditValue) / 1.0936133), 3);

   } etc

Comment: @Sin5k4 That’s what you’re doing at the moment, and it has the same problem: it will trigger the `TextChanged` event on the other control. And that in turn will trigger the `TextChanged` on the first control. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To prevent them going into an infinite loop,i get the sender in c#

It is unclear what you mean by that. In any case, you could do the same in VB.

In reality, comparing the `sender` doesn’t help you here because the `sender` is known: for `TextBox1_TextChanged` it is *always* `TextBox1`, and for `txtmt_TextChanged` it is always `txtmt`, unless you call the `*_TextChanged` event handlers manually somewhere else in code, and you shouldn’t do that.

The problem here is the following: if you change the contents of `txtmt` in `TextBox1_TextChanged`, that change is going to raise `txtmt_TextChanged`, and vice versa. We can prevent this by temporarily unhooking the event handler, effecting the change, and re-hooking it.

In VB, this is done via `RemoveHandler` and `AddHandler` (the equivalent in C# would be using `-=` and `+=`).

Another remark on the code: **Always use `Option Strict On` in VB.** This enables stricter type checking. There is a broad consensus that this option should always be on, and that there isn’t a good excuse for not using it (except when handling legacy COM interop). Your code wouldn’t compile with `Option Strict`.

It’s also a good idea to enable `Option Infer`.

With that, we have the following solution:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' FIXME: Use proper error handling via TryParse in real code!
    Dim value = Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

    ' Prevent raising the event.
    RemoveHandler txtmt.TextChanged, AddressOf txtmt_TextChanged
    txtmt.Text = (value * 0.9144).ToString()
    AddHandler txtmt.TextChanged, AddressOf txtmt_TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub txtmt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' FIXME: Use proper error handling via TryParse in real code!
    Dim value = Double.Parse(txtmt.Text)

    ' Prevent raising the event.
    RemoveHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = (value / 0.9144).ToString()
    AddHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
End Sub
```

Notice that in order to use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`, we unfortunately had to remove the `Handles` clause. This means that you have to hook these events up manually in the `Form_Load` event handler:

```
AddHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
AddHandler textmt.TextChanged, AddressOf textmt_TextChanged
```

Comment: That was quite useful.Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

use `If not (sender is nothing) andalso Ctype(sender,textbox).name=textbox1.name Then`

Instead of `If (sender Is TextBox1) Then`

Comment: No, that’s completely unnecessary. First off, you don’t need to check for `Nothing` because `sender` will never be `Nothing`. Secondly, use `DirectCast` instead of `CType`. Thirdly, do not cast and compare the name, it has no advantage over comparing for object equivalence. Your solution is essentially a bad way of doing what OP already does much better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Basically, 1. OP dont need to check whether the sender is textbox1 or not in his question, because that event itself listening for textbox1's textchange. 2.] _don’t need to check for Nothing because sender will never be Nothing._ suppose consider, if OP called that event manually like this `Dim xObj as Object = nothing call textbox1_textchanged(xObj,new eventargs)` , then sender will be nothing. So simply, this question is unclear to confuse the answerers, this downvote should have been given for this question...!

Comment: @KonradRudolph "sender will **NEVER** be Nothing." this is why i mentioned a case like that.!

Comment: Okay, let me amend this: if you program correctly, `sender` will never be nothing. If it’s nothing that is a *bug* in your application, and that *should* crash. Don’t guard against bugs with `If` statements.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  `If it’s nothing that is a bug in your application, and that should crash.` i dont think so, if you have any concrete proof about this (manually calling an event), then give me.. surely i will not follow this methodology again.! :)

Comment: This is a rather unproductive discussion. It’s simply an established engineering practice that you shouldn’t try to hide bugs in your code by guarding against them (this is somewhat related to the [fast-fail principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)). I don’t know what “concrete proof” you expect. If you want to know whether `sender` can ever be `Nothing` then just consult the documentation, which is unambiguous on this point: `sender` is a reference to the source of the event. This simply cannot be `Nothing`.